# Properly handling spaces and quotes in bash completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete, escaping, eval, quotes

What is the correct/best way of handling spaces and quotes in bash completion?

Here’s a simple example. I have a command called `words` (e.g., a dictionary lookup program) that takes various words as arguments. The supported ‘words’ may actually contain spaces, and are defined in a file called `words.dat`:

```
foo
bar one
bar two
```

Here’s my first suggested solution:

```
_find_words()
{
search="$cur"
grep -- "^$search" words.dat
}

_words_complete()
{
local IFS=$'\n'

COMPREPLY=()
cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$(_find_words)" -- "$cur" ) )

}
complete -F _words_complete words
```

Typing `‘words f<tab>’` correctly completes the command to `‘words foo ’` (with a trailing space), which is nice, but for `‘words b<tab>’` it suggests `‘words bar ’`. The correct completion would be `‘words bar\ ’`. And for `‘words "b<tab>’` and `‘words 'b<tab>’` it offers no suggestions.

This last part I have been able to solve. It’s possible to use `eval` to properly parse the (escaped) characters. However, `eval` is not fond of missing quotes, so to get everything to work, I had to change the `search="$cur"` to

```
search=$(eval echo "$cur" 2>/dev/null ||
eval echo "$cur'" 2>/dev/null ||
eval echo "$cur\"" 2>/dev/null || "")
```

This actually works. Both `‘words "b<tab>’` and `‘words 'b<tab>’` correctly autocompletes, and if I add a `‘o’` and press `<tab>` again, it actually completes the word and adds the correct closing quote. However, if I try to complete `‘words b<tab>’` or even `‘words bar\ <tab>’`, it is autocompleted to `‘words bar ’` instead of `‘words bar\ ’`, and adding for instance `‘one’` would fail when the `words` program is run.

Now, obviously it *is* possible to handle this correctly. For instance, the `ls` command can do it for files namned `‘foo’` `‘bar one’` and `‘bar two’` (though it does have problems with some ways of expressing the filenames when one uses a (valid) combination of  both `"`, `'` and various escapes). However, I couldn’t figure out how `ls` does it by reading the bash completion code.

So, does anybody know of how properly handle this? The actual input quotes need not be preserved; I would be happy with a solution that changes `‘words "b<tab>’`, `‘words 'b<tab>’` and `‘words b<tab>’` to `‘words bar\ ’`, for instance, (though I would prefer stripping of quotes, like in this example, instead of adding them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This not too elegant postprocessing solution seems to work for me (GNU bash, version 3.1.17(6)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)). (Unless I didn't test some border case as usual :))

Don't need to eval things, there are only 2 kinds of quotes.

Since compgen doesn't want to escape spaces for us, we will escape them ourselves (only if word didn't start with a quote). This has a side effect of full list (on double tab) having escaped values as well. Not sure if that's good or not, since ls doesn't do it...

EDIT: Fixed to handle single and double qoutes inside the words. Essentially we have to pass 3 unescapings :). First for grep, second for compgen, and last for words command itself when autocompletion is done.

```
_find_words()
{
    search=$(eval echo "$cur" 2>/dev/null || eval echo "$cur'" 2>/dev/null || eval echo "$cur\"" 2>/dev/null || "")
    grep -- "^$search" words.dat | sed -e "{" -e 's#\\#\\\\#g' -e "s#'#\\\'#g" -e 's#"#\\\"#g' -e "}"
}

_words_complete()
{
    local IFS=$'\n'

    COMPREPLY=()
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$(_find_words)" -- "$cur" ) )

    local escaped_single_qoute="'\''"
    local i=0
    for entry in ${COMPREPLY[*]}
    do
        if [[ "${cur:0:1}" == "'" ]] 
        then
            # started with single quote, escaping only other single quotes
            # [']bla'bla"bla\bla bla --> [']bla'\''bla"bla\bla bla
            COMPREPLY[$i]="${entry//\'/${escaped_single_qoute}}" 
        elif [[ "${cur:0:1}" == "\"" ]] 
        then
            # started with double quote, escaping all double quotes and all backslashes
            # ["]bla'bla"bla\bla bla --> ["]bla'bla\"bla\\bla bla
            entry="${entry//\\/\\\\}" 
            COMPREPLY[$i]="${entry//\"/\\\"}" 
        else 
            # no quotes in front, escaping _everything_
            # [ ]bla'bla"bla\bla bla --> [ ]bla\'bla\"bla\\bla\ bla
            entry="${entry//\\/\\\\}" 
            entry="${entry//\'/\'}" 
            entry="${entry//\"/\\\"}" 
            COMPREPLY[$i]="${entry// /\\ }"
        fi
        (( i++ ))
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for the original examples, but if I add ‘rock 'n roll’ to words.dat, it fails. My real-life use of the autocompletion actually involves words with apostrophes, and that’s the reason I originally used `eval`. It’s easy enough (though not very elegant) to fix, by adding an extra ‘search and replace’ to the `for loop, and then add another for loop for strings beginning with '. The only remaining problem, as far as I can see, is that the autocompletion does not advance one cursor position if you have written an entire word, including any closing quotes.

Comment: Regarding my comment above. It looks like the situation is slightly worse than I thought. Auto-completion inside a word containing apostrophes (e.g., trying to autocomplete ‘rock 'n ro’, either written using escaped spaces and apostrophe, or single or double quotes) doesn’t work. The reason is that the `search` variable is not in its correct expanded form. Some extra substitutions seems possible, but I haven’t been able to get this to work correctly for all the three different ways of escaping.

Comment: Yes, compgen seems to be stripping all qoutes... Which means they must be escaped inside _find_words

Comment: If you need to handle some other special characters ($, `, {, ( or whatever else bash might take offence on -- didn't test those), just escape them in similar way -- first backslash, then everything else in 2 or 3 places.

Comment: There are still some things that doesn’t work, e.g. completing `"rock 'n`. Most of these can be fixed by removing `"$cur"` from the `_find_words` call. Then everything works for strings that starts with a double quote or nothing, except when ‘completing’ an already complete word starting with a double quote (since the last double quote incorrectly gets quotes?). And there are still some problems with completing words beginning with a single quote (only the last part of the word seems to be recognised when the completion suggestion is inserted). But all in all, this solution works OK. Thanks!

Comment: Also if you have trouble completing arguments like "text 'more_text" where is a single quote inside double quotes, you can try `COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$(_pyxbindman_get_choices)" -- "${cur/\'/\'}" ) ) ` instead of the similar line in the script (it escapes single quotes, compgen needs that by some reason).

Answer (score 29):

The question is rather loaded but this answer attempts to explain each aspect:

1. How to handle spaces with `COMPREPLY`.
2. How does *`ls`* do it.

There're also people reaching this question wanting to know how to implement 
the completion function in general.  So:

3. How how do I implement the completion function and correctly set `COMPREPLY`?

## How does *`ls`* do it

Moreover, *why does it behave differently to when I set `COMPREPLY`?*

Back in '12 (before I updated this answer), I was in a similar situation and searched high and low for the answer to this discrepancy myself.  Here's the answer I came up with.

`ls`, or rather, the default completion routine does it using the `-o filenames` functionality. This option performs: *filename-specific processing (like adding  a  slash to directory names or suppressing trailing spaces*.

**To demonstrate:**

```
$ foo () { COMPREPLY=("bar one" "bar two"); }
$ complete -o filenames -F foo words
$ words ░
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
$ words bar\ ░          # Ex.1: notice the space is completed escaped
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
bar one  bar two        # Ex.2: notice the spaces are displayed unescaped
$ words bar\ ░
```

Immediately there are two points I want to make clear to avoid any confusion:

- First of all, your completion function cannot be implemented simply by setting `COMPREPLY` to an array of your word list!  The example above is *hard-coded* to return candidates starting with b-a-r just to show what happens when <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed.  (Don't worry, we'll get to a more general implementation shortly.)
- Second, the above format for `COMPREPLY` only works because `-o filenames` is specified.  For an explanation of how to set `COMPREPLY` when not using `-o filenames`, look no further than the next heading.

Also note, there's a downside of using `-o filenames`: If there's a directory lying about with the same name as the matching word, the completed word automatically gets an arbitrary slash attached to the end. (e.g. `bar\ one/`)

## How to handle spaces with `COMPREPLY` without using `-o filenames`

Long story short, it needs to be escaped.

**In contrast to the above `-o filenames` demo:**

```
$ foo () { COMPREPLY=("bar\ one" "bar\ two"); }     # Notice the blackslashes I've added
$ complete -F foo words                             # Notice the lack of -o filenames
$ words ░
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
$ words bar\ ░          # Same as -o filenames, space is completed escaped
```

<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
bar\ one  bar\ two      # Unlike -o filenames, notice the spaces are displayed escaped
$ words bar\ ░
```

## How do I actually implement a completion function?

Implementing a completion functions involves:

1. Representing your word list.
2. Filtering your word list to just candidates for the current word.
3. Setting `COMPREPLY` correctly.

I'm not going to assume to know all the complex requirements there can be for 1 and 2 and the following is only a very basic implementation.  I'm providing an explanation for each part so one can mix-and-match to fit their own requirements.

```
foo() {
    # Get the currently completing word
    local CWORD=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

    # This is our word list (in a bash array for convenience)
    local WORD_LIST=(foo 'bar one' 'bar two')

    # Commands below depend on this IFS
    local IFS=$'\n'

    # Filter our candidates
    CANDIDATES=($(compgen -W "${WORD_LIST[*]}" -- "$CWORD"))

    # Correctly set our candidates to COMPREPLY
    if [ ${#CANDIDATES[*]} -eq 0 ]; then
        COMPREPLY=()
    else
        COMPREPLY=($(printf '%q\n' "${CANDIDATES[@]}"))
    fi
}

complete -F foo words
```

In this example, we use `compgen` to filter our words.  (It's provided by bash for this exact purpose.)  One could use any solution they like but I'd advise against using `grep`-like programs simply because of the complexities of escaping regex.

`compgen` takes the word list with the `-W` argument and returns the filtered result with one word per line.  Since our words can contain spaces, we set `IFS=$'\n'` beforehand in order to only count newlines as element delimiters when putting the result into our array with the `CANDIDATES=(...)` syntax.

Another point of note is what we're passing for the `-W` argument.  This argument takes an `IFS` delimited word list.  Again, our words contain spaces so this too requires `IFS=$'\n'` to prevent our words being broken up. 
 Incidentally, `"${WORD_LIST[*]}"` expands with elements also delimited with what we've set for `IFS` and is exactly what we need.

In the example above I chose to define `WORD_LIST` literally in code.

One could also initialize the array from an external source such as a file.  Just make sure to move `IFS=$'\n'` beforehand if words are going to be line-delimited such as in the original question:

```
local IFS=$'\n'
local WORD_LIST=($(cat /path/to/words.dat))`
```

Finally, we set `COMPREPLY` making sure to escape the likes of spaces.  Escaping is quite complicated but thankfully `printf`'s `%q` format performs all the necessary escaping we need and that's what we use to expand `CANDIDATES`.  (Note we're telling `printf` to put `\n` after each element because that's what we've set `IFS` to.)

Those observant may spot this form for `COMPREPLY` only applies if `-o filenames` **is not used**.  No escaping is necessary if it is and `COMPREPLY` may be set to the same contents as `CANDIDATES` with `COMPREPLY=("$CANDIDATES[@]")`.

Extra care should be taken when expansions may be performed on empty arrays as this can lead to unexpected results.  The example above handles this by branching when the length of `CANDIDATES` is zero.

Comment: Your first example doesn't actually work.  TAB TAB gets you the list ok, but when you try "words bar t<TAB>" it fails.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the purpose of the example.  If you want to actually implemented a bash completion routine, it takes a lot more than just setting COMPREPLY to a static array.  I'm sure there're more appropriate questions on SO that deal specifically with this.

Comment: if u say so.  i took the liberty of providing a fully working example of your example, as an answer.

Comment: you can also `unset IFS` as soon as it's served its purpose. That way subsequent commands can be simplified (e.g. no need to `printf ;%q\n`)... see https://github.com/iterative/shtab/pull/106/commits/9bfda44735463fb552b41099420a4e7bd118a674

Comment: @casper.dcl It doesn't seem so.  It's a local variable so it's already unset automatically at the end of the function.  The need for `printf %q` has nothing to do with `IFS`.  I've replied to the commit you linked detailing how unsetting it before `compgen -W` is damaging.

Answer (score 5):

```
_foo ()
{
  words="bar one"$'\n'"bar two"
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
  cur=${cur//\./\\\.}

  local IFS=$'\n'
  COMPREPLY=( $( grep -i "^$cur" <( echo "$words" ) | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' ) )
  return 0
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _foo words
```

Comment: Why are you escaping `.` into `\.` on `$cur`?

Comment: But bash substitutions are never regular expressions, *right?* Consider: `text='foo.bar'; echo "${text//./_}"` - that works as a literal replace of the dot on GNU bash 4.3.11 (Linux) and 3.1.20 (Windows).

Comment: But when it's passed to grep, grep is going to interpret it as a regular expression.

Comment: What I mean is, `cur=${cur//./\\.}` has the same effect. Or should, that's why I'm asking. (By the way, one alternative to using `grep` in this case is to separate by line, trim each line to the length of the pattern string, and test if both are identical - this is what I'm using as it's not only faster  when using just builtins but avoids other characters that have special meaning for grep).

Comment: Apparently you are correct.  `cur=${cur//./\\.}` works, as does `cur=${cur//.\\\.}`.  Must be pure reflex after seeing that `/` to go into regex mode.  as for faster inline methods, fabulous idea, but auto-complete files are already so hard to read for other people.

Comment: Since this is indeed rather hard to read I've made it into a function that one can "just use". Only shell builtins, multiple prefixes possible, case insensitive option, and just pipe stdin and give line prefixes as parameters. http://pastebin.com/weMpizK6

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (out of all the current answers in SO). Thanks, @Orwellophile !

Comment: @ttsiodras Thanks, that's because I only come to SO when I'm trying to solve my own problems, and when I'm not satisfied with the answers I find, I work it out myself, and return to supply a *decent answer*.  It doesn't earn me many points, but comments like yours do make it worthwhile.

Comment: omg, some ass just downvoted without explanation. i'm not an SO point-_w_hore, but seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe `_find_words` through `sed` and have it enclose each line in quotation marks.  And when typing a command line, make sure to put either `"` or `'` before a word to be tab-completed, otherwise this method will not work.

```sh
_find_words() { cat words.dat; }

_words_complete()
{

  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

  local IFS=$'\n'
  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( _find_words | sed 's/^/\x27/; s/$/\x27/' )" \
                         -- "$cur" ) )

}

complete -F _words_complete words
```

Command line:

```
$ words "ba░
```

<kbd>tab</kbd>

```
$ words "bar ░
```

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

```
bar one  bar two
$ words "bar o░
```

<kbd>tab</kbd>

```
$ words "bar one" ░
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating my own function compgen2 which handles the extra processing when the current word doesn't begin with a quote character. otherwise it works similar to compgen -W.

```
compgen2() {
    local IFS=$'\n'
    local a=($(compgen -W "$1" -- "$2"))
    local i=""
    if [ "${2:0:1}" = "\"" -o "${2:0:1}" = "'" ]; then
        for i in "${a[@]}"; do
            echo "$i"
        done
    else
        for i in "${a[@]}"; do
            printf "%q\n" "$i"
        done
    fi
}

_foo() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
    local words=$(cat words.dat)
    local IFS=$'\n'
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen2 "$words" "$cur"))
}

echo -en "foo\nbar one\nbar two\n" > words.dat
complete -F _foo foo
```