# Muti word command completion for bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Properly handling spaces and quotes in bash completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146098/properly-handling-spaces-and-quotes-in-bash-completion)

I would like to be use muti-word quoted strings for bash completion.

e.g. I like to be able to do this

```
$ command <tab> 
  "Long String 1"
  "Long String 2"
```

where "Long String 1" and "Long String 2" are the suggestions given when tab is pressed.

I tried using this  where `~/strings`  contains a list of quoted strings

```
function _hista_comp(){
    local curw
    COMPREPLY=()
    curw=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '`cat ~/strings`' -- $curw))    
    return 0
}
complete -F _hista_comp hista
```

The above function splits the string on whitespace. Is there any way to make it return the whole quoted string?

e.g if `~/string` had the following lines

```
  "Long String 1"
  "Long String 2"
```

It would give 5 suggestions instead of 2.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146098/properly-handling-spaces-and-quotes-in-bash-completion. And the answer seems to be that `compgen` doesn't play nicely with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying various things I found that adding

```
    IFS=$'\x0a';
```

to the start of the function (changes the input separator to new line)  makes the function handle spaces correctly.

So the function would be

```
function _hista_comp(){  
    IFS=$'\x0a';
    local curw
    COMPREPLY=()
    curw=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '`cat ~/strings`' -- $curw))    
        uset IFS
    return 0
}
complete -F _hista_comp hista
```

This would allow

```
$ command <tab> 
  "Long String 1"
  "Long String 2"
```

as I wanted.

Comment: Or, more simply, `IFS=$'\n'`. By the way, the function in your answer is identical to the function in your question (I think you forgot to add the `IFS` line - I would make it `local`, too).