# Handle Bash completion after/within opened single-/doublequote

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion, quotations

I'd like to provide proposals for an argument that has to be quoted just like this:

```
$ cmdx 1starg 'argtwoa %1 %x argtwob'
```

The interaction should go like this (expectation):

```
$ cmdx 1starg '[TAB TAB]
argtwoa argtwoc %1
$ cmdx 1starg 'argtwob[TAB TAB]
argtwoa argtwoc %1
$ cmdx 1starg 'argtwob
```

However, if I've typed the first word (one of the proposed) as the second argument, Bash does not give more examples but closes the opened quotation:

```
$ cmdx 1starg 'argtwob'
```

My completion function looks like this so far:

```
function _complete() {
    local cur prev args
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    # echo "## prev=|$prev| cur=|$cur| words=[$COMP_CWORDS[@]] word=|${COMP_CWORD}| ##"

    if [ ${COMP_CWORD} -eq 1 ]; then
        args="1starg"

        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${args}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    elif [ ${COMP_CWORD} -ge 1 ]; then
        args="argtwoa argtwob argtwoc %1"

        if [[ "${cur}" =~ ^\'[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]$ ]]; then
            args="%1"
        fi

        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${args}" -- ${cur}) )

        # echo "####|${COMREPLY}|#|${args}|####"
        return 0
    fi
}

complete -F _complete cmdx
```

When I uncomment the second debug-`echo` and press tab after the second argument has been opened with a singlequote and the first word and a space and then press `TAB` I expect "%" to be printed as a proposal.
The debug output confirms, that my code is correct until `compgen` runs:

```
$ cmdx 1starg 'argtwoa ####||#|%1|####
```

I suspect, it's not possible to do what I want as the resulting `args` value is correct but not the `COMPREPLY` value (debugged using `echo`).

The same should work for doubleqoutes too (I know, that I have to extend the code).

Comment: Have you looked at [Properly handling spaces and quotes in bash completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146098/properly-handling-spaces-and-quotes-in-bash-completion)?

Comment: To whoever: what's that for a manner voting for close with reason "unclear what the TO is asking" instead of leaving a comment or just moving on.